# Windows 10 python executable can´t run on Windows 7 Professional

Tags: python, windows-10, windows-7, pyinstaller, executable

I´m developing a tkinter GUI that will run another python script, using python 3.8 and Pycharm in Windows 10, but the goal is to create an executable to run in Windows 7 Professional, since I can´t install python in the other Windows 7 computer or even update its Windows system.

Once the executable is created, with pyinstaller 5.7.0, I have successfully managed to run it in the Windows 7 Professional computer, but once I push a button in it to run the python script, an error just pulls off saying:

"The "python" command is either misspelled or couldn't be found."

I must also say that the command that I am using to run the python script from the tkinter GUI is:

```
import os
os.system("python 'scriptname'.py")
```

Do you have any idea why this problem is happening? Are there any solutions? What should I do?

I expect the windows 10 python executable to run on windows 7 professional, and the GUI to run another python script, all in an executable.

I have also tried different commands to open the python script, but its always followed by errors:

```
subprocess.call(['python', 'scriptname.py'])
# error: The system couldn´t find "subprocess.py" file

subprocess.call(['python', 'scriptname.py'], shell=True)
# error: "The "python" command is either misspelled or couldn't be found."

subprocess.run(['python', 'scriptname.py'], shell=True)
# error: "The "python" command is either misspelled or couldn't be found."
```

Comment: Has your oldest Windows 7 PC installed Python and work well in command line mode (cmd.exe)?

Comment: os.system and subprocess.call interact with the shell, since you don't have python installed, the only option is to turn those scriptname.py into exes themselves

Comment: All `os.system`, `subprocess.call` requires a namespaced command well-served already in the terminal (simply saying, they're *installed*).

Comment: @Misinahaiya My oldest Windows 7 PC has never installed Python and I can´t install it there

Comment: @Martheen so basically I should turn the scriptname.py into exe and then put them in the same folder as the GUI exe and everything should run fine then?

Comment: Here is link that telling you .... https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

Comment: @toyotaSupra what do you mean with that link?
Apparently python 3.8 is still compatible with Windows 7

Comment: Pyinstaller does not provide a python executable in it's compiled programs.  If the pc that runs the executable does not already have python installed then any subprocess calls to run python scripts will not work.